# How to enable NTLM support for curl Rust crate?

Tags: curl, rust, libcurl, ntlm, rust-cargo

I build on windows with cargo.toml settings:

```
[dependencies]
curl = {version="0.4.33", features = ["ssl"]}
```

Then when I call http service I get an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error 
{ description: "A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl 
due to a build-time decision.", code: 4, extra: None }'
```

How to enable NTLM support for curl Rust crate?

Answer (score 2):

The [rust curl crate](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust) will attempt to link against the existing curl library on your system if it can find it. In that case, you will only be able to use features which are compiled into that existing curl library.

Going by the error you are getting, I would assume that NTLM was not enabled when your curl library was compiled. You can check that by running the curl cli progam (which is usually linked to the library) with the `-V` option:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.43.0 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets Metalink
```

If you enable the crate feature `static-curl` then it will build the curl library itself and statically link it. It appears that it will enable all applicable features in that scenario (although I have not tested that).

Comment: I have no system wide curl command, I build on Windows 10. I tried static-curl feature and unfortunately it didn't help. spnego works fine, but I need NTLM.

Comment: @IgorTkachenko and what OS are you running on? if it's windows, what do you get from `cd \; dir *curl* /s /b`, if it's not windows, what do you get from `find / -iname "*curl*" 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm running on the same OS, just cargo run with cargo.toml: `curl = {version="0.4.33", features = ["ssl", "static-curl"]}`. `where /r c:\ *curl*.dll *curl*.exe` search found several dll and exe file in other programms - git, LibreOffice, Apache web Server, Visual Studio to name a few. Most of these exe files have NTLM feature. But on PATH I have no curl command. Shouldn't my cargo run build use it's own curl If I use "static-curl"?

Comment: @IgorTkachenko right, which dlls? add it to pastebin or something, but chances are 1 of those dlls is the problem, because i'm guessing Rust is accidentally loading the wrong curl dll

Comment: @hanshenrik I used `procexp64.exe` to find out which libraries my executable is loading. It turned out that it does not load libraries whose name would contain curl. According to this issue [link](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/issues/321) I always had a statically linked curl, which is what I really want. But in statically linked curl NTLM doesn't work. Now it looks like a bug in curl Rust crate.